# Checks for whether sysdate is equal to transaction date in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I have a table named courseInfo with the following structure

```
Name   ClassName Date_Tx              Remarks   
JON    WONDERS   2018-04-04 10:00:00   NULL
```

I need to check that whenever the transaction date (Date_Tx) is equal to sysdate and also the remarks column is null, I need to return 1 or 0.

what i have tried

To check whether remarks is null in the table

```
select decode(remarks, null, 'FALSE', 'TRUE') BOOL_VAL from courseInfo;

select * from courseInfo where date_tx = sysdate;
```

I am not sure on how to merge both queries to get the desired output. Any help is greatly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: `sysdate` includes the time, as does your column. (As do all dates; I mean you column has times other than midnight.) Are you really looking for an exact match, to the second? Or just on the same day, at any time?

Comment: @AlexPoole I need to make sure that the date_tx falls within the current day and remarks is null and not an exact match. Thanks

Comment: The condition to check for should look like `where remarks is null and trunc(date_tx) = trunc(sysdate)`. `trunc` rounds date values to the day. So if you need to introduce an indicator column that would look like `select case when remarks is null and trunc(date_tx) = trunc(sysdate) then 1 else 0 end as marker from courseInfo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you only want the date portion to match, not the time-of-day, you need to somehow ignore the time-of-day.

The "lazy" way, which many inexperienced programmers use, is to write the condition as `trunc(date_tx) = trunc(sysdate)`. (One such programmer just did that in a Comment under your question.) Fight the temptation!

The correct way to write this condition is

```
date_tx >= trunc(sysdate) and date_tx < trunc(sysdate) + 1
```

This way, you avoid the function call to `trunc()` on each row. Better, if you have an index on `date_tx` (which you should have, if many of your queries use the `date_tx` in filters), the version I wrote above will allow the index to be used. If you wrap `date_tx` within `trunc()`, the index can't be used.

Alternatively, if you often write queries based ONLY on the date portion (and you don't use the time-of-day), you can create a **function-based** index on `trunc(date_tx)` - and then, indeed, write the condition as

```
trunc(date_tx) = trunc(sysdate)
```

But that's about the only time you should write it that way!

Comment: @ mathguy - It was indeed a great detailed explanation and thanks for answering.